# Update a Google Sheet w/ API Data

Tags: rest, google-sheets, zapier, ifttt

I'm using Google Sheets along with App Sheet to make a simple mobile app that tracks product inventory for me. It's working great. But I'd like to use a 3rd party API to bring in additional product info.  I know how I can use IFTTT or Zapier to make a 3rd party API call, but I can't figure out how to make a 3rd party API call and then update my Sheet with the response. Is this possible?  Thanks!T

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

That's definitely possible! The first thing you'll want to do is decide on a trigger. Is this row only updated once (on creation) or on some other impetus (such as a different field being updated). For sake of example, let's assume creation. Your zap would look like this:

1. Trigger: New Row Created
2. Action: Code Step / Webhook Step (to fetch info)
3. Action: Update Row (using the data from steps 1 & 2)

There's more info about updating rows in the help docs here: https://zapier.com/help/google-sheets/#updating-rows

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!